# nreco live streaming over udp System.IO.IOException error

Tags: c#, video, stream, udp

I am developing a udp server for live video streaming using c#. I am using nreco wrapper to encode my frames, this is the thread that i call to compress a list of frames :

```
 private void comp_tread()
    {
        while (true)
        {

            mre.WaitOne();//Blocks the current thread until the current WaitHandle receives a signal.
            var videoconv=new FFMpegConverter();
            List<Bitmap> copyofframes = new List<Bitmap>();//list to copy the frames to encode
            copyofframes = framestoencode.ToList();
            framestoencode.Clear();

            var h264stream = new MemoryStream();

            string outPutFrameSize = _frameWidth.ToString() + "x" + _frameHeight.ToString();
            int g = _framerate * 2;
            var ffMpegTask = videoconv.ConvertLiveMedia(//some code);
                ffMpegTask.Start();


            foreach (var item in copyofframes)
            {

                var bd = item.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, item.Width, item.Height), ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);
                var buf= new byte[bd.Stride * item.Height];//The stride is the width of a single row of pixels (a scan line), rounded up to a four-byte boundary
                Marshal.Copy(bd.Scan0, buf, 0, buf.Length);
                ffMpegTask.Write(buf, 0, buf.Length);// i get the error here
                item.UnlockBits(bd);
            }
            ffMpegTask.Stop();
            h264stream.Close();
            mre.Reset();//Sets the state of the event to nonsignaled, causing threads to block
        }
    }//end of compression thread
```

on the line of ffMpegTask.Write(buf, 0, buf.Length); i get the following error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.IO.IOException' occurred in
>   mscorlib.dll. Additional information: The pipe has been ended.

Any ideas?

--edit--
i have spoken with nreco support.for anyone have the same problem that is their answer."Write method provides input data to the ffmpeg with redirected stdin; this error means that ffmpeg process and stopped and data cannot be written to ffmpeg's stdin. In most cases this happen when input data doesn't correspond parameters for the ConvertLiveMedia call (for example, bitmap size doesn't match specified frame size) -- as result error occurs and ffmpeg process is exited. I recommend to handle LogReceived event and analyze ffmpeg console log output to find the reason why it stops working."

Comment: i have spoken with nreco support.for anyone have the same problem that is their answer."Write method provides input data to the ffmpeg with redirected stdin; this error means that ffmpeg process and stopped and data cannot be written to ffmpeg's stdin.
In most cases this happen when input data doesn't correspond parameters for the ConvertLiveMedia call (for example, bitmap size doesn't match specified frame size) -- as result error occurs and ffmpeg process is exited.

I recommend to handle LogReceived event and analyze ffmpeg console log output to find the reason why it stops working."